# Why does nesting this awk command with eval produce a different result than running it?

Tags: bash, awk

I have this script that's designed to assign variables to commands that collect information about a system and then echo them back. This works very well for the first few commands, but the last one continues to return the value without "PRETTY_NAME=" stripped out of the output.

Is there some problem with this that I'm not seeing?

I have tried using grep to separate awk:

`grep PRETTY_NAME /etc/*-release | awk -F '=' '{print $2}'`

Using escaped quotes:

`awk -F \"=\" '/PRETTY_NAME/ {print $2}' /etc/*-release`

Whole block (edited somewhat for relevance)

```
declare -A CMDS=(
   [primaryMacAddress]="cat /sys/class/net/$(ip route show default | awk '/default/ {print $5}')/address" 
   [primaryIpAddress]="hostname --ip-address"
   [hostname]="hostname"
   [osType]="awk -F '=' '/PRETTY_NAME/ {print $2}' /etc/*-release"
   )

#This bit is actually nested in another function
for kpair in "${!CMDS[@]}" do
   echo "$kpair=\"$( eval ${CMDS[$kpair]} )\""
done
```

Results when run from .sh file:

> osType="PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)""

expected:

> osType=""Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)""

When this command is run by itself, it seems to work as intended:

> $ awk -F '=' '/PRETTY_NAME/ {print $2}' /etc/*-release
>
> > "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.4 (Maipo)"

Comment: The `$2` gets expanded inside double quotes. Use `\$2` instead. Or just...use functions, this is terrible :)

Comment: @PesaThe Unfortunately due to the structure of the rest of the script, this is the best way that I could manage this section, but this did fix my issue. Thank you.

Comment: The first entry should have the same problem with `$(ip route...)` expanding prematurely. If that's actually a problem.

Comment: @ncfx1099 In shell, the use of `eval` is nearly always a bad choice.  You might want to ask another question where you explain the "structure of the rest of the script" and why that leads you to this code.  I expect that people will be able to offer you better approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your Awk command is specified in double quotes, interior dollar signs are subject to special treatment: the `$2` is treated as a parameter substitution by your shell, and so the array element doesn't store the text `$2` but rather its expansion. The Awk interpreter never sees the `$2` syntax.

However, you have a second problem in your command dispatcher. Your `eval` command does not prevent word splitting:

```
eval ${CMDS[$kpair]}
```

you want this:

```
eval "${CMDS[$kpair]}"
```

without the quotes, your command is arbitrarily chopped into fields on whitespace. Then `eval` catenates the pieces together, using one space between them, and evaluates the resulting syntax. The difference can be demonstrated with the following example:

```
$ cmd="awk '/foo/ { print \$1\"    \"\$2 }'"
$ echo 'foo a' | eval $cmd
foo a
$ echo 'foo a' | eval "$cmd"
foo    a
```

We can just use `echo` to understand the issue:

```
$ echo $cmd
awk '/foo/ { print $1" "$2 }'
$ echo "$cmd"
awk '/foo/ { print $1"    "$2 }'
```

The substitution of `$cmd` and the subsequent word splitting is done irrespective of any shell syntax that `cmd contains. We can see the pieces like this:

```
$ for x in $cmd ; do echo "<$x>" ; done
<awk>
<'/foo/>
<{>
<print>
<$1">
<"$2>
<}'>
```

When we execute `eval $cmd`, the above pieces are generated and re-combined by `eval` and evaluated. Needless to say, you don't want your command syntax to be chopped up and re-combined like this; who knows what sort of hidden bug will arise. It may be okay for the commands you have now, but as a generic command dispatch mechanism, it is flawed.

Comment: Thanks! In the original script I was passing in that value as a string, functionally. I didn't know about the string splitting and will keep that in mind.